# Select by Date range of dates

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I want to select PostgreSQL rows based on Date range. I tried this:

```
Date start;
Date end;

ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE WHERE START_DATE = ? AND END_DATE = ?");

ps.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) start);
ps.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) end);
```

But I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at com.crm.web.schedule.Schedule$1.loadEvents(Schedule.java:62)
```

How I can properly select range of dates?

Comment: ps.setDate(1,  new java.sql.Date(start.getYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDay()));
ps.setDate(2,  new java.sql.Date(end.getYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDay()));

Comment: I get the same wrong result.

Comment: then ps.setDate(1, start);
ps.setDate(2, end);

Comment: I get error that I need to cast the dates from util to sql date.